# How to Prove It Exercise 7.2.5

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Prove that ${}^{\mathbb{Z}^+} \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+) \sim \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+)$ where ${}^A B$ means the set of all functions $f:A \rightarrow B$ and $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is the power set of $A$.

To prove this I need to find a function $F:{}^{\mathbb{Z}^+} \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+)$ which is one-to-one and onto. Please can anyone give me a small hint on how to start defining this function. I am having difficulty in finding an unambiguous of taking an arbitrary function in ${}^{\mathbb{Z}^+} \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+)$ and somehow associating with it a subset of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:** Don't work hard, work smart. Recall, or prove, that ${}^C({}^BA)\sim{}^{C\times B}A$. Now use the facts that $\mathcal P(X)\sim{}^X2$ and that $\Bbb{Z^+}\sim\Bbb{Z^+\times Z^+}$.

Comment: Thank you! I should have figured that out by myself since I was asked to prove those things in an earlier part of the question.